# Not fully installing Kali

Tags: kali-linux

So I finally got it working to install kali-Linux on my windows 11. I tried to do the full download to install it Metasploit as well as the other tools that come with Kali However I got this error. I have hyper-V, virtualization, WSL enabled. My computer is (dell) xps 15 2021 edition.

*First I type sudo apt install -y kali-Linux default I followed this video in how to install metasploit in kali on windows 11- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hLFwtW6Xns
then I get an error:

dpkg: error processing package python3-frozenlist (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I've tried to fix it with sudo apt --fix-missing update, sudo apt --fix-broken install
. it Doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... it cannot be copied and searched on the internet ... please delete the picture and add the text itself

Comment: I did. BUt I couldn't show the full list of errors. though. So I'll try add a picture again.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text

Comment: Please show the beggining of command or output where the error starts

Comment: @cevhyruz I tried it wouldn't let me post the whole thing. or the beginning not enough characters sorry. Its the same though through out. that kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what the issues further up were but from the screen shot, it looks like you're missing Python3 according to the statement `... depends on python3`

Try

`sudo dpkg --list | grep python3`

to verify if it is installed. If its not installed, use

`sudo apt-get install python3`

I don't think this will resolve all the issues but hopefully get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I tried that didn't work. I posted some examples of the error that I'm referring to. Does that now get you a better idea of what I'm having trouble with? I couldn't post all of it.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you're having an issue with dependencies for your packages to where some larger packages aren't being "activated" due to missing dependencies. I'm having a similar issue myself if you check my latest post.

Try checking your key signature to make sure its up-to-date, that can cause an issue with some packages (there's a link on how in my post too)

This may not resolve your issue but you can check that off the list

Comment: how do I do that?